# Force developers to use predefined list of attributes as function argument

Tags: python

How do I prevent developers from using `get_tax()` function with literal `tax` argument like `get_tax(1000, 0.23)` and force them to use predefined list?

```
class TaxRates:
    vat=0.23
    pit=0.15
    
def get_tax(price, tax):
    return price*tax

get_tax(1000, TaxRates.vat)  # should succeed
get_tax(1000, 0.23)  # should fail
```

Or is there better approach to go about this?

Comment: Someone is sure to write an answer, but in the meantime: maybe take a look at pythons enums https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work, rather than pass the tax as a float pass a string or constant that can be looked up against the valid options. Using this the only valid values are "vat" or "pit"

An Enum would probably work too if you wanted to have the taxes in a structure as before

```
VAT = 'vat'
PIT = 'pit'
tax_rates = {
    VAT: 0.23,
    PIT: 0.15
}
    
def get_tax(price, tax):
    try:
        rate = tax_rates[tax]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(f'Unknown tax "{tax}"')
    return price * rate

get_tax(1000, VAT)
```

Answer (score 1):

In compile time, the arguments of the functions are getting evaluated. So `TaxRates.vat` is evaluated to `0.23` and `tax` finally gets the "literal" value `0.23`. You can't check that this way.

One solution would be to check if the value get passed by `tax` is one of those class attributes(better to use `Enum`), otherwise raise an error.

```
import enum

class TaxRates(enum.Enum):
    vat = 0.23
    pit = 0.15

def get_tax(price, tax):
    if tax not in [i.value for i in TaxRates]:
        raise ValueError(f'tax parameter {tax} is not acceptable')
    return price * tax


print(get_tax(1000, 0.23))  # Fine
print(get_tax(1000, 0.21))  # Error
```

Comment: Can you give example of checking if value passed via `tax` is class attribute?